# Getting both progress and dots in Rails test logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

We are getting both dots and progress bar in our Minitest logs, e.g.

```
.  413/198: [==============================================================                                                                       ] 47% Time: 00:02:59,  ETA: 00:03:1
.  413/199: [===============================================================                                                                      ] 48% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:03:1
.....  413/204: [=================================================================                                                                    ] 49% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:
..  413/206: [=================================================================                                                                    ] 49% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:03:
.  413/207: [==================================================================                                                                   ] 50% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:03:0
..  413/209: [==================================================================                                                                   ] 50% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:02:
..  413/211: [===================================================================                                                                  ] 51% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:02:
...  413/214: [===================================================================                                                                  ] 51% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:02
.  413/215: [=====================================================================                                                                ] 52% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:02:4
.  413/216: [=====================================================================                                                                ] 52% Time: 00:03:02,  ETA: 00:02:4
```

And for the life of me I can't figure out how to suppress the dots.  We have the `minitest-reporters` gem installed and this configuration:

```
require 'minitest/reporters'

Minitest::Reporters.use!(
  Minitest::Reporters::ProgressReporter.new,
  ENV,
  Minitest.backtrace_filter
)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Dealing with the same thing and also struggling to figure out why. Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug in `Minitest::Reporters`](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/issues/230).

> [@samcday](https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/issues/230#issuecomment-326444197):
>   Add this workaround to `test_helper.rb` directly after requiring everything.

```rb
# This is a workaround for https://github.com/kern/minitest-reporters/issues/230
Minitest.load_plugins
Minitest.extensions.delete('rails')
Minitest.extensions.unshift('rails')
```